# Laravels 'Should Queue" resets mail text to default

Tags: laravel, notifications, queue

i have a problem woth combining notifications and queue in laravel...

if i dont use queue and write notification like this

```
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class InterestingOfferPosted extends Notification
{
    public $offer;
    public function __construct($offer)
    {
        $this->offer = $offer;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->subject('New Offer')
                    ->line("You have new offer:  ".$this->offer->name }
    }
```

this works fine, i get correct text at the end, however if i get this class to implement "Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue" class and use "Illuminate\Bus\Queueable" trait users are receiving default laravels "The introduction to the notification." mail. 
queues are working nice in any other cases, so i think i got that right, but in this particular case it alters final result.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not implementing queue interface here

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class InterestingOfferPosted extends Notification  implements ShouldQueue{      
 use Queueable;
```

Comment: when i do it sends blank mail, like it doesn't touch toMail() method